# Migrate Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange, migration

I have to migrate the exchange server to another machine running the newer version of it (2010).

On the old machine is currently the domain controller and exchange 2007 installed.
The domain controller has to be kept on the old machine.

What is the best way to migrate the exchange server without loosing any data.

On the exchange 2007 server are following services installed: 
- Client Access,
- Hub Transport,
- Messaging Server,
- Mailbox Server

The old machine's hostname is subdomain1.domain.local, the newer ones should be subdomain2.domain.local!

I have read something about preparing the ActiveDirectory for Exchange 2010 - what about that?

Thanks for your answers,
Alexander

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! What you are asking is either too broad or would lead to extended discussions.  Per the [Help Section](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask), your question should be reasonably scoped. **If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare to do some reading...you're in for the long haul with this. I'm posting this link as the answer because there's far too much to summerize: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638158(v=exchg.141).aspx